# Textures of leaves

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]

I downloaded bunch of images of leaves but a can't apply them properly, because they are basically squares. Should i use photoshop? Or blender has a way to cut them?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to alpha-mask the images in Photoshop or Gimp but if you have your leaf on a black background, you can do it in blender [like this.](https://youtu.be/H5KcOwCL6RA)
Alternatively, you can download already masked leaf images from sites like [textures.com](https://www.textures.com/search?q=Leaves&filter=masked).

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you make the color around the leaf from green and whatnot, to completely transparent and use a Transparent BSDF node if you are using Cycles:

[image: Texture transparency node setup]